# Interfaces and hierarchy in Go (migrating from Java)

Tags: go, inheritance, interface

I'm rewriting some old Java app to Go. This application is built on JAXB technology and has classes hierarchy projectable to XML. I rewrote most of app without any problems but one feature seems for me is implemented not in a proper way. I'll give you example.

There is a basic abstract class Command with method toXML and a lot of descendants (really more than 1 level deep)

```java
class Command {
    String id;
    String toXML() {
        // every descendant of Command use this method to marshall its structure to XML
    }
}

class SendCommand extends Command {
    String sendData;
}
```

In Go I implemented this code below.

```golang
type ToXMLInterface interface {
    ToXML()
}

type Command struct {
    id string
}

func (Command) ToXML() {}

type SendCommand struct {
    Command
    sendData string
}

func (SendCommand) ToXML() {}

func ToXML(value ToXMLInterface) string {
    m, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(value, "", "   ")
    return string(m)
}
```

But for me it looks a little weird and I would want to simplify it. Is there some way to do it more simple? (Maybe without implementing empty interface for each class?)

Comment: Go doesn’t have inheritance, don’t try to model types like you would in Java.

Comment: To complement JimB's comment, forget about type hierarchy and focus instead of the behaviour(s) that types exhibit.

Comment: Your approach doesn't look that off to me. A couple comments: there's already a way to encode in xml via `encoding/xml.Marshaler`. You're already using `xml.MarshalIndent` so it's not clear what value this added interface has.

Comment: Interface has no own value. It is some kind of "marker" interface, just to specify which kind of structs can be passed to marhalling function.

Answer (score 1):

The major fact there is about interfaces in Go is that they work "backwards" to what you may be used to in other mainstream languages. In Go, types implement interfaces implicitly, and a type potentially implements any number of interfaces. This sounds weird but here's a simple example:

```golang
type T struct {}

func (t T) Foo() int {
  return 42
}

func (t T) Bar() string {
  return "42"
}


type F interface {
  Foo() int
}

type B interface {
  Bar() string
}


var f F = T{}
var b B = T{}
var t T

b = t
f = t
```

This is valid Go code (it won't compile as is but not because of incorrectness).
As you can see, the type `T` does not embed anything declared as `type ... interface ...` nor does it use any other way to "implement" interfaces `F` and `B`, and still it's easy to see it implements both of them.
This works because the checks for whether a type implements a particular interface happen at compile time or at runtime when Go has a value of some non-interface type and needs to type-convert it to some interface type.

I would recommend to read [this classic piece](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) on interfaces (written by one of the Go core devs) to get the full picture.

In your particular case, you only need to embed "more basic" types into "more specialized" types if some of the methods of these basic types are actually useful to be promoted to become methods of the specialized types.
I mean, if `Command` would have `toXML` which could be used "as is" by all the other types it gets embedded into, that would be a valid reason for embedding; otherwise there isn't.

Note that it could be guessed `toXML` is precisely the method which each "specialized" type needs to define diffetently, but suppose `Command` would also provide something like `getStringID()` which would be the same across all "specialized" types. Then it'd be a good idea to embed `Command` into all those types: they would get that method implemented automagically.

And in the end, when programming in Go, the rule of thumb is what JimB and jub0bs said: don't get drowned in designing type hierarchies; instead, implement types which perform particular tasks. Doing this, you might eventually detect that some set of types would benefit from embedding some common type *or types;* only then go on and do that.

Comment: Thanks for a complete explanation. As for remarks of JimB and jub0bs - this structs have no own behaviour, it's only used for interaction with other remote system

Comment: @ArtemZyuzko, then you really can just embed `Command` into them. Just do not think about this as inheritance; it's not some sort of egghead academic advice, it really helps to have a correct mental model for a given PL being used.